# Why isn't the bridge network starting?

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-bridge

I need to create a bridge network on my Ubuntu host

I followed tutorials [like this](https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/) to create a bridge interface in nmapplet.

I made sure to remove all other VPNs, bridges, and even shut down the docker service so I don't have any other network interface besides `lo`.

However, when I try to add the bridge, it can never seem to start up.

Here's a picture of the network interface failing to start.

[image: Here]

I've checked kernel logs and syslogs, and I'm not seeing any errors related to `br0`. What other logs can I check to determine what the issue is?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.